# Printing Parallel Tuples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm trying to make a word guessing program and I'm having trouble printing parallel tuples. I need to print the `"secret word"` with the corresponding hint, but the code that I wrote doesn't work. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated :)

This is my code so far:

```
import random

Words = ("wallet","canine")
Hints = ("Portable money holder","Man's best friend")
vowels = "aeiouy"
secret_word = random.choice(Words)
new_word = ""


for letter in secret_word:
    if letter in vowels:
        new_word += '_'
    else:
        new_word += letter

maxIndex = len(Words)

for i in range(1):
        random_int = random.randrange(maxIndex)
print(new_word,"\t\t\t",Hints[random_int])
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `random_int` is, as defined, random. As a result you'll randomly get the right result sometimes.

A quick fix is by using the `tuple.index` method, get the index of the element inside the tuple `Words` and then use that index on `Hints` to get the corresponding word, your print statement looking like:

```
print(new_word,"\t\t\t",Hints[Words.index(secret_word)])
```

This does the trick but is clunky. Python has a data structure called a dictionary with which you can map one value to another. This could make your life easier in the long run. To create a dictionary from the two tuples we can `zip` them together:

```
mapping = dict(zip(Words, Hints))
```

and create a structure that looks like:

```
{'canine': "Man's best friend", 'wallet': 'Portable money holder'}
```

This helps.

Another detail you could fix is in how you create the `new_word`; instead of looping you can use a comprehension to create the respective letters and then `join` these on the empty string `""` to create the resulting string:

```
new_word = "".join("_" if letter in vowels else letter for letter in secret_word)
```

with exactly the same effect. Now, since you also have the dictionary `mapping`, getting the respective hint is easy, just supply the key `new_word` to `mapping` and it'll return the key.

A revised version of your code looks like  this:

```
import random

Words = ("wallet", "canine")
Hints = ("Portable money holder", "Man's best friend")
mapping = dict(zip(Words, Hints))
vowels = "aeiouy"
secret_word = random.choice(Words)

new_word = "".join("_" if letter in vowels else letter for letter in secret_word)

print(new_word,"\t\t\t", d[secret_word])
```